# MinGW GCC Fatal Error - gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

Today my gcc suddenly broke and I don't know how to fix.

Here `gcc 1.c` I got
`gcc.exe: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`

I've tried many methods on the Internet, including:

- Add 'C:\MinGW\bin' to system path.
- Reinstall MinGW
- Reboot
- Install the Nuwen's MinGW distribution.

They all don't work.

But the Nuwen's distribution gave me more information when I type `gcc 1.c`:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

It seems that `gcc` cannot find `cc1.exe`. However `cc1.exe` is not missing. It stays at the right path, and is callable. If I type `cc1.exe ...`, it works properly and returns with no error or warning.

Here's more information:

`gcc -v 1.c`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --with-zstd=/c/mingw --disable-bootstrap
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT 1.c -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase 1.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -version -o C:\Users\delux\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrtSf2l.s
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/cc1.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

`gcc -print-search-dirs`:

```
install: c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/
programs: =c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
libraries: =c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/temp/gcc/dest/mingw/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;C:/temp/gcc/dest/mingw/lib/../lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../;C:/temp/gcc/dest/mingw/lib/
```

There's another MinGW in my computer, but I didn't add their dirs to the system path variable. My OS is Win10.

By the way, this problem occurred when I did a simulation in Xilinx ISE 14.7. But all the MinGW gcc in my computer became not working together, reporting the same error.

Is there any solution? Thanks!

[UPDATE] The problem is solved by stopping MacType in my computer. I didn't realize that this error had something to do with MacType. Though I still don't know why, but at least the problem is solved. Thank you all.

Regards,
D.

Comment: So it seems as if the Xilinx installation gets in the way. Did you try to uninstall that?

Comment: @thebusybee I tried. Neither of un-installation nor re-installation work.

Comment: Strange. I tried to call "cc1" without any prefix, and my CMD does not find it. Did you try `where gcc` and `where cc1` to see which one is used?

Comment: @thebusybee It's strange, indeed. At first `where cc1` returns nothing. So I added it into the system path. Now `gcc` is `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` and `cc1` is `C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.2.0\cc1.exe`, which is correct I think. But `gcc 1.c` still failed with the same error.

Comment: I think it is normal that "cc1" cannot be called with path, I mean that its path is not in "PATH". "gcc" should know how to call it, and as the verbose output shows, it tries so. But I have no idea why the system thinks that it cannot be found. -- There are mixed slashes and backslashes in the "-iprefix" option. Did you build GCC yourself?

Comment: @thebusybee No. I use the official MinGW-w64. I also tried Nuwen's MinGW distribution.

Comment: @thebusybee The problem is solved! Thank you for your concern. :)

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question. This will help others looking here for help. IIRC you need to let pass some time before you can mark it. You might want to take the [tour] and read some of the [help] to learn how this site works. ;-) It is not a forum.

Comment: Got it! My first time asking a question on StackOverflow. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of trying, I finally found the cause for my problem.

It turned out that the MacType running on my computer somehow made the MinGW broken. So the solution is rather simple: **terminate the MacType program**.

If you still want to use MacType with MacTray, **compatibility mode** could be your choice. Do not use standalone mode!

I haven't figured out why MacType made my MinGW not work properly. If you have any clue, please feel free to make a comment!

Answer (score 1):

When I try to upgrade gcc MicroSoft Defender tells me it put
D:\msys64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.2.0\cc1.exe
in quarantaine because it contains
VirTool:Win32/Obfuscator.IY
So I think also your case cc1.exe was blocked by a virus protector and you are now using a substitute.